# Why does my javascript file sometimes compressed while sometimes not?(IIS Gzip problem)

Tags: javascript, iis, caching, compression, gzip

i enable gzip for javascript file in my iis settings, here 's the corresponding config section.

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="10" dynamicCompressionLevel="8" />
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
  <add mimeType="application/soap+msbin1" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
  <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

currently, when i download my js file, it seems that sometimes server return the gzip one, and sometimes not. i dont know why, and how to debug that.

If a file is already gzipped, it should be cached in local disk, and next time someone visit that file again, iis kernel should return the cache gzip file directly without compressing it again. Is that right?

Comment: Can you post request and response bodies in both cases (when file is compressed and not)? You can use Fiddler in IE and FireBug in Firefox.

Comment: hi, artem, i'm a web developer, i know how to check if response is gzipped. and i 'm sure it's not gzipped. and luckily, i figure it out, that it's an iis bug. i write a post about this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jaf, i figure it out myself, there might be some bug in iis. you can set the frequenthitthreshold option to force the script file to always gzip the file.
i write a post about this bug, but it's in chinese, here 's the google translated version
[Why gzip not work in IIS7?](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imkevinyang.com%2F2010%2F05%2F%25E4%25B8%25BA%25E4%25BB%2580%25E4%25B9%2588iis77-5%25E7%259A%2584gzip%25E4%25B8%258D%25E8%25B5%25B7%25E4%25BD%259C%25E7%2594%25A8.html&sl=zh-CN&tl=en)

Answer (score 1):

The fix indeed seems to be setting the frequentHitThreshold attribute to 1 on the system.webServer/serverRuntime node in the applicationHost.config file. Documented at http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/serverRuntime.

You can do this by executing the following command as an administrator:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:serverRuntime /frequentHitThreshold:1 /commit:apphost
```

A word of warning - the "frequent hit" concept does not seem specific to compression. I have no idea whether there are other consequences as a result of setting this!

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache, and try again.

Comment: there's nothing about client cache. it's all about the server